# tmux-powerline is displaying on multiple lines

Tags: zsh, tmux

I posted an issue found at on the github link below, but in short, I can't get zsh to work properly. I'm open to suggestions.

https://github.com/erikw/tmux-powerline/issues/125

Answer (score 0):

Do you have UTF characters in your prompt? If so, make sure you have these settings in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
# use UTF8
set -g utf8
set-window-option -g utf8 on
```

Some UTF characters will take an extra space, causing some weird formatting of tmux-powerline.